# POST fails when using replace in my Python API POST request

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, post, replace

I have a JSON dump that I am trying to post to a another application. In the payload there is a `"pageGroups": "['TEST_TCIS:Oncall Schedule']",` and the double quotes need to be removed to represent this output to pass the data: `"pageGroups": ['TEST_TCIS:Oncall Schedule'],`

I have tried to use `replace` but it fails. If I manually remove the double quotes out of the JSON payload it works.

Here is the code:

```
api_url_base = "some url"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer some token"
     }
data = {"abendCode": "",
        "action": "CREATE",
        "assignGroup": "TCIS-APP-SUPPORT",
        "component": "tcis",
        "description": "Test incident creation",
        "entered": "", "logicalName": "tcis",
        "pageGroups": "['TEST_TCIS:Oncall Schedule']",
        "priority": "",
        "racfId": "",
        "sendPage": "",
        "sysProdName": "tcis",
        "transactionId": "",
        "type": "SYSMAN"}

data = json.dumps(data)
data = data.replace("\"[", "[").replace("]\"", "]")
print(data)


response = requests.post("https://apistaging.csx.com/tcis-events/v1/events",
                         json=data, headers=headers)
response_url = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(response_url)
print("response " + str(response))
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
{"abendCode": "",
 "action": "CREATE",
 "assignGroup": "TCIS-APP-SUPPORT",
 "component": "tcis",
 "description": "Test incident creation",
 "entered": "",
 "logicalName": "tcis",
 "pageGroups": ['TEST_TCIS:Oncall Schedule'],
 "priority": "",
 "racfId": "",
 "sendPage": "",
 "sysProdName": "tcis",
 "transactionId": "",
 "type": "SYSMAN"}

{'traceId': 'd9dcd6ee-a0f3-170c-83e5-a52f2133cd31', 'error': {'code': 'APG400', 'message': 'The server could not process the request.'}}
response <Response [400]>
[Finished in 0.789s]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the double quotes from the already JSON-formatted data you get `['TEST_TCIS:Oncall Schedule']`, but this isn't valid JSON anymore. If this is supposed to be a list containing one string, the string needs to be quoted with double quotes (`"`) in JSON.

To do this properly, remove the quotes from the value first, and *then* convert it to a JSON string.

In fact, "removing the quotes" from `"['TEST_TCIS:Oncall Schedule']"` means to parse a string representation of a list into a list, for which there is [`ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list).

```
import ast
import json

data = {"abendCode": "",
        "action": "CREATE",
        "assignGroup": "TCIS-APP-SUPPORT",
        "component": "tcis",
        "description": "Test incident creation",
        "entered": "", "logicalName": "tcis",
        "pageGroups": "['TEST_TCIS:Oncall Schedule']",
        "priority": "",
        "racfId": "",
        "sendPage": "",
        "sysProdName": "tcis",
        "transactionId": "",
        "type": "SYSMAN"}

data['pageGroups'] = ast.literal_eval(data['pageGroups'])
data = json.dumps(data)
print(data)

#response = requests.posts(..., json=data, ...)
```

Output (line breaks added manually):

```
{"abendCode": "",
 "action": "CREATE",
 "assignGroup": "TCIS-APP-SUPPORT",
 "component": "tcis",
 "description": "Test incident creation",
 "entered": "",
 "logicalName": "tcis",
 "pageGroups": ["TEST_TCIS:Oncall Schedule"],
 "priority": "",
 "racfId": "",
 "sendPage": "",
 "sysProdName": "tcis",
 "transactionId": "",
 "type": "SYSMAN"}
```

Comment: It worked, but I had to maintain the json.dumps in the code and use (..., data=data, ...) for it to pass a 200, otherwise I was getting a 400.